# Add text fields to a TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I am trying to develop an application and I can not fill in the TextAreas:

```
var txt= window.localStorage.getItem("phrase");
var area=document.getElementById(window.localStorage.getItem("id_travail"));
$(area).val(txt);
```

Comment: make a jsfiddle...it becomes easy 4ppl 2debug

Comment: Works great for me: http://jsfiddle.net/zH2Na/. Perhaps you are not setting the value of `localStorage['id_travail']` to the id of your textarea correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to tell jQuery that area is an ID unless you are defining it in
    window.localStorage.getItem("id_travail")

```
$("#"+area).val(txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine (here is a [functional fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zH2Na/)). Your problem is either:

1. The value returned by `window.localStorage.getItem("id_travail")` does not match the ID of any textarea on the page.
2. Your code is running before the DOM is built, so `document.getElementById` cannot find the textarea, since it doesn't exist yet as a DOM element. Try wrapping your code inside a `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` so that the code only runs after the DOM is built.